# While trying to use selfTracking I'm receiving Client error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I'm using SelfTracking in entity framework.

The problem is that when I save data everything works fine but when I save it second time it want to add new object but I only want to update old one or don't do anything if the one wasn't modified.

I will describe it below:

I have User entity. I create it, do sth and then I create Context, Save it and the destroy Context but User isn't destroyed.

It works ok, User is saved in Database. Then I invoke the same method. Create new context, save and there is duplicate key violation (it doesn't know that it has to update user but tries to insert it).

```
Context.User.ApllyChanges(MyUser);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

I tried different variations and each time there is the same error. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for help.

When I click save new Context is created but I have the same EntityObject  which I had. Then it wants to add new object

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with POCO (not self tracking) but I believe it also applies.

The thing is that you must know if it is a New or and Update and add the object to the context and change its state to [modified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423414%28VS.91%29.aspx). If you leave it as added EF will try to insert it into the db.

Comment: Isnt this the whole case that SelfTracking knows what happened to the object was it added modified or anything. I would like that After save state of the User object should be reset so that next time I save if it wasnt modified it would want to add it :/ What if user has got a lot of collecions: Products, Cars ... should I everywhere set modified ?

Comment: I know that's what I do :) but again, I haven't worked with self-tracking... but how would your server side know what ever happened on the client?

Comment: Because selfTracking object has got metaData in which there is an information what happened.